# how to use waypoints

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I'm new to waypoints and don't get it to work

This is my HTML

```
<section class="progress center" id="progress">
<h3>Skills</h3>
<div class="bars">
    <div class="progressbar">
        <h4>Concepting & Research</h4>
        <progress value="75" max="100" class="bar"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="progressbar">
        <h4>UX design</h4>
        <progress value="85" max="100" class="bar"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="progressbar">
        <h4>Sketch</h4>
        <progress value="90" max="100" class="bar"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="progressbar">
        <h4>Framer</h4>
        <progress value="60" max="100" class="bar"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="progressbar">
        <h4>HTML5 & CSS</h4>
        <progress value="65" max="100" class="bar"></progress>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JQuery function I want to trigger when the progressbars come in to the viewport

```
$(function() {
  $(".bar").each(function() {
    var fill = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(0).animate({value: fill}, {duration: 750});
  });
});
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('progress'),
  handler: $(function() {
    $(".bar").each(function() {
      var fill = $(this).val();
      $(this).val(0).animate({value: fill}, {duration: 750});
    });
  })});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
            element: $(".test")[2],
            handler: function(direction) {
                alert('Scrolled to test4!'+direction);
            },
            offset: '20%'
                //offset:100 //offset top  you should append this property.
        })
```